# Meaning of class(*)() in gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, most-vexing-parse

I'm having trouble understanding this compiler error.  I wrote class(*)() in the post title because the class I am instantiating is called "opaque", but that name is not informative or relevant.  It is a templatized Circular Buffer and some tests.  I am using the opaque class to test the data structure with full class/struct types. I am also testing with primitives (int at the moment) and that test function does not give me this compiler error.  There is more code than this, but I've provided what I think are the relevant sections.
The full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/3196485) if you are interested.

gcc error:

```
tests.cpp: In function ‘bool opaque_fill_test(int)’:
tests.cpp:97:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘CircBuf<opaque>::remove(opaque (*)())’
```

tests.cpp:

```
struct opaque {
  int id;
  opaque(int n): id(n) {} 
  opaque operator=(const opaque &o) { this->id = o.id; }
};

opaque rcv();
CircBuf<opaque> c(size);
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if ( c.remove(&rcv)) {
        if (rcv.id != i ) {
            cout << "wrong value: " << rcv << " "
            << "should be: " << i << endl;
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "remove fail at i=" << rcv << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

CircBuf.h:

```
template<typename T> class CircBuf {
    ...
    template<typename T> bool CircBuf<T>::remove(T *t) {
       ...
       *t = data[front];
       ...
```

if i declare an opaque* and pass that to remove instead:

```
opaque rcv();
opaque* p = &rcv;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
  if ( c.remove(p)) {
    ...
    ...
```

i get a similar error:

```
tests.cpp: In function ‘bool opaque_fill_test(int)’:
tests.cpp:96:16: error: cannot convert ‘opaque (*)()’ to ‘opaque*’ in initialization
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the declaration `foo x();`, the expression `&x` will actually be a function pointer assignable to something like `foo *(y)()`. The `p` variable in your last example isn't such a function pointer, but simply a pointer to an `opaque` struct. Thus you cannot assign the function pointer to that variable.

[edit]
Just remembered: maybe you meant to declare an `opaque` variable and initialize it using the default constructor. Leave out the parentheses then. It's a left-over syntax from C. You can only use the parentheses there if you actually put values in between to call a different constructor.

Comment: I believe the `opaque rcv();` is inside a function definition, in which case it's just a regular function declaration, not a method. The error message should otherwise not say `opaque (*)()`, but something like `opaque (class::*)()`.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. But the point is, he mixed pointers to data with pointers to executable code and the compiler rightfully complained. ;) My guess is that he mistook the `foo bar();` syntax for initialization with the default constructor.

Comment: `opaque` doesn't have a default constructor, so `opaque rcv;` shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with:

```
opaque rcv();
```

is that you are "declaring a function" with the name `rcv` having the return type `opaque`, and taking no arguments. [Check this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Drop the paranthesis:

```
opaque rcv;
```

Answer (score 0):

You hit the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

> if i declare an opaque* and pass that to remove instead:
>
> ```
> opaque rcv();
> ```

That declares a function returning `opaque`, not a default-initialized `opaque`. Instead use `opaque rcv;` or `opaque rcv = {};`.

As for the error message, `opaque (*)()` is the type of a pointer to a function returning `opaque`. The name of the "function" was implicitly converted to a pointer when used for something besides a call.